# Error with Images service after converting to Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm in the process of switching an application over from Python 2.5 to 2.7 and have begun encountering a problem with the images service.  For example, saving this entity using db.put():

```
from google.appengine.api import images

class Images(db.Expando):
    ImageTitle = db.StringProperty()
    ImageFile = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    ImageReference = db.StringProperty()

    def put(self, **kwargs):                    
        if not self.ImageReference:
            self.ImageReference = images.get_serving_url(self.ImageFile.key())
        super(Images, self).put(**kwargs)
```

Now yields this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\VB User\Bruha\src\handler_product_page_image.py", line 40, in post
    image.put()
  File "C:\Users\VB User\Bruha\src\db_models.py", line 56, in put
    self.ImageReference = images.get_serving_url(self.ImageFile.key())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 1792, in get_serving_url
    rpc = get_serving_url_async(blob_key, size, crop, secure_url, filename, rpc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 1907, in get_serving_url_async
    None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 1034, in _make_async_call
    rpc = create_rpc()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\images\__init__.py", line 1028, in create_rpc
    return apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC("images", deadline, callback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 405, in __init__
    self.__rpc = CreateRPC(service, stubmap)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 69, in CreateRPC
    'a CreateRPC method.') % service)
AssertionError: The service "images" doesn't have a CreateRPC method.
```

Calling the 'execute_transforms' method also yields the same error.

Any help understanding what is going on would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running the dev server, so when you start up check for this message `'Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing '
                    'the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: %s', e

If you are getting this message then the images service RPC is not being registered (the `RegisterStub` call in dev_appserver will be failing) and you will get the error you are seeing, because the assertion fails in `CreateRPC` call.

So check to see if PIL is correctly installed for Python 2.7